# Why the performance drops if the number of process is greater than half the number of cores?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing, centos7

Hi guys I have the following Python program which is to benchmark the performance of multi-processing application.

```
#
# Date : 09/May/2018
# Platform : Linux
#

import os
import sys
import ctypes
import signal
import multiprocessing as mp

ncpu = 4
counter = 0
child_index = 0
process_list = []
shared_array = None

def HandleSignal(signum, frame) :

   total = 0
   print("Parent timeout hence terminate child")
   [hProc.terminate() for hProc in process_list]
   [hProc.join() for hProc in process_list]
   for each_count in shared_array :
      total += each_count
   print("{:,}".format(total))

def ChildHandleSignal(signum, frame) :

   # print("{} - {} : {:,}".format(child_index, os.getpid(), counter))
   shared_array[child_index] = counter
   sys.exit(0)

def entry_point(index, sarr) :

   global counter
   global child_index
   global shared_array

   child_index = index
   shared_array = sarr
   signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, ChildHandleSignal)
   while True : counter += 1

   return

ncpu = int(sys.argv[1])
maxcpu = os.cpu_count()

if ncpu > maxcpu :

   print("Number of CPU greater than maximum CPU")
   print("Setting number of CPU to maximum")
   ncpu = maxcpu

shared_array = mp.Array(ctypes.c_int64, range(ncpu))
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, HandleSignal)
signal.alarm(5)

for I in range(ncpu) :

   p1 = mp.Process(target=entry_point, args=(I, shared_array, ))
   process_list.append(p1)
   p1.start()

   # I tried both with and with-out the below
   # statement. The outputs are much similar
   os.sched_setaffinity(p1.pid, {I})
```

I have run this program on two different machines

1. Google cloud VM with Cent OS 7.x running on 8 VCPU Intel processor
2. Cent OS 7.X Linux machine with 48 core Intel processor

The plotting of output vs number of core used is as shown below. From which I observer that the output increases until the numbe-of-process reaches number-of-cores / 2 and declines after that. Can someone explain this behavior ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: wild guess - hyper threading

Comment: But hyper-threading should increase the performance but here the performance has dropped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @IlyaBursov the "problem" here is Hyper threading.

Hyper threading is not just magic. The true purpose of hyper threading is to be able to execute another process or thread, during the delay waiting for memory access of the other process.

And in your case, your code is way too simple to gain performance using hyper threading. This is just a counter incremented in an infinite loop. All the code can be put in the L1 cache, there is surely no cache miss...

But if you add too much process, the cost of the context switch between 2 processes is not negligible.